# How to sort a list of table rows via javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Say I have this html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Sort Order</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="item" id="item_1">
    <td class="sortorder">1</td>
    <td>ABC</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="item" id="item_2">
    <td class="sortorder">2</td>
    <td>DEF</td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="item" id="item_3">
    <td class="sortorder">3</td>
    <td>XYZ</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is for a user to be able to sort the rows in the table (excluding the first row with the `<th>`s, so all rows with the class `.item`) by dragging and dropping them, and then update their sort orders.

E.g if user drags DEF to first position and ABC replaces it, I want DEF's sort order to say 1, and ABC's to say 2 instead.

How can this be done?

If needed, I can have all the items stored seperately in a javascript array or object so I can loop over them and update each item's sort order whenever the user changes the sort order.

Comment: I would suggest checking out Datatables for something like this. http://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery UI's sortable list. Its well supported across browsers and has many options and callbacks. They use a list in their example but you could just as easily use a table.

jQuery UI Sortable Documentation - http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/
Sortable tutorial/guide - http://www.petefreitag.com/item/736.cfm

Example:

```
$('table').sortable({
    items : '.item',
    update : function(event, ui)
    {
        alert('sort order updated');

        // Display sort order - also checkout serialize() method in jQuery UI Docs
        alert('sort order: ' + $(this).sortable('toArray').toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post some code on how to get the new order of the items whenever its updated?

Answer (score 1):

There are several, already-written table sorting plugins for jQuery:

- http://tablesorter.com/docs/
- http://www.datatables.net/index
- others ?